# Jquery Parse XML File

Tags: php, jquery, xml, parsing

I've got the following code from another example on this site. This is reading the XML data from with in the same script.

How would I move the XML to an external page and have this script read that in ? Both php and XML files will be in the same location on the server.

Everything I've tried has resulted in Uncaught Error: Invalid **'test.xml'** messages.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var select = $('#ID'),
        xml = $($.parseXML($('#XMLData').text())),
        plans = xml.find('plan');

    plans.each(function () {
        var ID = $(this).find('ID').text();
        select.append("<option>" + ID + "</option>");
    });

    $("#ID").change(function () {
        var selectedIndex = $('#ID option').index($('#ID option:selected')),
            plan = $(plans[selectedIndex]);

        $('#planNumber').val(plan.find('planNumber').text());
        $('#Area').val(plan.find('Area').text());
        $('#Name').val(plan.find('Name').text());
        $('#Description').val(plan.find('Description').text());
        $('#Station_ID').val(plan.find('Station_ID').text());

        $('#code').val(plan.find('code').text());
        $('#County').val(plan.find('County').text());
    }).trigger('change');
});
</script>

<script type='text/xml' id='XMLData'>
  <XMLReview>
    <plan>
      <planNumber>773</planNumber>
      <Area>Upper Missouri</Area>
      <ID>MISSOURI-NUT</ID>
      <Name>Missouri River</Name>
      <code>10030101</code>
      <County>Broadwater</County>
      <Station_ID>M09MISSR05</Station_ID>
    </plan>
    <plan>
      <planNumber>774</planNumber>
      <Area>Columbia</Area>
      <ID>FLAT-STILL-TPA-2013</ID>
      <Name>Sheppard Creek</Name>
      <Description>- 3A</Description>
      <code>17010210</code>
      <County>Flathead</County>
      <Station_ID>C09SHEPC04</Station_ID>
    </plan>
  </XMLReview>
</script>
<form>
    ID <select type="text" name="ID" id="ID"></select><br/>
    planNumber<input type="text" name="Name" id="planNumber"><br/>
    area<input type="text" name="Area" id="Area"><br/>
    Name:  <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name"><br/>
    Description:  <input type="text" name="Description" id="Description"><br/>
    Station ID  <input type="text" name="Station_ID" id="Station_ID"><br/>
    <label class="Code-label" for="code">HUC</label>
    <select class="select_code" id="code" name="code" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
      <option></option>
      <option>10010001</option>
      <option>10010002</option>
      <option>10020001</option>
      <option>10030101</option>
      <option>17010210</option>
    </select>
    <br/>
    <label class="county-label" for="County">County</label>
    <select class="select_county" id="County" name="County" data-iconpos="left" data-icon="grid">
     <option></option>
     <option>Beaverhead</option>
     <option>Big Horn</option>
     <option>Blaine</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: Where you used `test.txt`?

Comment: Sorry Typo when creating this post. Should read test.xml

I'll update my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save your `xml data` only in `test.xml` and then try this,

```
$(function(){
    var select = $('#ID');
    function renderData(xml,plans){
        plans.each(function () {
            var ID = $(this).find('ID').text();
            select.append("<option>" + ID + "</option>");
        });

        select.change(function () {
            var selectedIndex = $('#ID option').index($('#ID option:selected')),
                plan = $(plans[selectedIndex]);

            $('#planNumber').val(plan.find('planNumber').text());
            $('#Area').val(plan.find('Area').text());
            $('#Name').val(plan.find('Name').text());
            $('#Description').val(plan.find('Description').text());
            $('#Station_ID').val(plan.find('Station_ID').text());

            $('#code').val(plan.find('code').text());
            $('#County').val(plan.find('County').text());
        }).trigger('change');   
    }

    $.get('test.xml',function(data){/// get the xml data from test.xml
        xml = $($.parseXML(data));// parse the data to xml
        plans= xml.find('plan');// find plans from xml
        renderData(xml,plans);//  call renderdata function to render elements
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work. No errors are shown. The form is displayed but nothing is displayed.

Comment: Changed the $.get to `$.get(url)
  .done(
    function (xml) {
      var $xml = $(xml);
      var plans = $xml.find('plan');
      ...
    }
  );` and now it works. Thanks

Comment: Anyway I can call the PHP page and pass it the planNumber and have those values selected by default ? eg `test.php?plannumber=773` and the values form `MISSOURI-NUT` populate the form by default ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Ajax methods:

```
$.get(url)
  .done(
    function (xml) {
      var $xml = $(xml);
      var plans = $xml.find('plan');
      ...
    }
  );
```

If the webserver delivers the file as XML (Content-Type) jQuery will return it in an DOM document. Wrap it into a jQuery object and use the CSS selectors to extract data.

Comment: Thanks using this and the code from Rohan works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to load external xml file (let's say data.xml) into your document then read it with javascript. add this line into `$(document).ready(function() {`:

```
$('#result').load('data.xml');
```

and add this to your html body

```
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but won't that just load the XML to the DIV ?

I'm trying to parse it then populate a select and depending on whats selected update the form fields.

Comment: well yes, since you already have the part where you parse xml from body, i figured you could change the object you're reading and be done with it.

Comment: Also i'd advice you to use database or at least json file to keep your data. XML is the worst efficient among them, well after plain text file that is.

Comment: This does load into results, but I'm not sure who I would make that work with what I already have.

Comment: change `xml = $($.parseXML($('#XMLData').text())),` to `xml = $($.parseXML($('#result').html())),`